# Change pdf file name in report definition Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Given this report definition, how can I change the file name used in the PDF so it uses names such as "SO-001.pdf".

```
<report
        id = "report_custom_sale_order"
        string = "Quotation / Order"
        model = "sale.order"
        report_type = "qweb-pdf"
        file = "custom_saleorder.report_saleorder"
        name = "custom_saleorder.report_saleorder"
        paperformat = "custom_saleorder.paperformat_a4"
/>
```

Odoo 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field you are looking for is `print_report_name`. Help text for the field says:

> This is the filename of the report going to download. Keep empty to not change the report filename. You can use a python expression with the object and time variables.

The field is defined on `ir.actions.report.xml`. [See the definition here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/report/models/ir_actions_report_xml.py#L10).

Simplest way to use it is via web UI: **Settings -> Reports -> Reports**
Choose the desired report and fill in the **Printed Report Name** field.

For example I have something like this there:
`'ABC_' + ('Sale_Order' if object.state == 'sale' else 'Quotation') + '_' + object.name + '.pdf'` which will result to: ABC_Sale_Order_SO0001.pdf

The expression [is evaluated here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/report/controllers/main.py#L108), if you'd like to see where the magic happens ;)

Comment: I don't know why this answer is not selected as correct. Thanks @ruuter

Comment: Do you know how to replace ABC with customer name ?

Comment: @Carlo you can get partner name with `object.partner_id.name`

Comment: Thanks, but `'object.partner_id.name' + ('prodajni nalog' if object.state == 'sale' else 'ponuda') + ' ' + object.name + '.pdf'` does not work for me

Comment: @Carlo `object.partner_id.name` should not have ' quotes around it

Comment: This is the right answer, however it is worth to mention that it does not work with the alias `<report>` in Odoo 10. It seems it works in Odoo 11. This is probably making people have issues with `print_report_name`. See this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760602/odoo-10-qweb-report-define-filename-for-pdf-file

Comment: @M.E. not sure what you mean, but my example works well in v10. Have not tried 11 yet :)

Comment: `print_report_name` does not work in Odoo 10 **when used with the alias `<report>`**, see attached post.

Answer (score 1):

For giving your custom pdf file name use field "**report_name**".

For more information and any help related qweb report you can refer following link:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html

Comment: `report_name` is literal string. OP was asking to have dynamic name, like SO_001.pdf. Unfortunately there is no word about it in the Docs. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use attribute `string`.

```
 <report id="action_report_followup"
   model="account_followup.followup"
    string="Follow-up Report"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="payment_followup.report_followup"
    file="payment_followup.report_followup"
     menu="True"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: `string` is literal string. OP was asking to have dynamic name, like SO_001.pdf. See my answer.