# Odoo 10 Qweb Report, define filename for PDF file

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have the following custom report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
  <report
        id = "report_custom_sale_order"
        name = "custom_saleorder_v2.custom_report_saleorder"
        string = "Custom Quotation / Order"
        model = "sale.order"
        report_type = "qweb-pdf"
        report_name = "((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
        attachment_use = "False"
  />

</odoo>
```

I would like the PDF to be downloaded as `SO003.pdf` for sales order with reference/sequential `SO003`, and as `SaleOrder.pdf` for sales order in draft without assigned reference/sequential.

When I try to implement such behaviour with report_name I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: report, line 11
```

How `report_name` shall be used?

---

Following CZoellner comment I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <report
        id = "report_custom_sale_order"
        name = "custom_saleorder_v2.custom_report_saleorder"
        string = "Custom Quotation / Order"
        model = "sale.order"
        report_type = "qweb-pdf"
        attachment_use = "False"
    />
    <record id="report_custom_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="print_report_name"><![CDATA[((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')]]></field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

And I got the following error:

```
ParseError: "null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (523, 1, null, 1, 2018-02-13 17:17:20.385168, null, 2018-02-13 17:17:20.385168, ir.actions.report.xml, null, null, t, pdf, null, null, null, null, null, t, null, f, null, null, null, f, null, null, ((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')).
" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/custom_addons/custom_saleorder_v2/reports/sale_report.xml:12, near
<record id="report_custom_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="print_report_name">((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')</field>
</record>
```

Note: it is the same if I use `object.name` instead of `object.number` (which I think it is the right way of getting the reference/sequential of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `print_report_name` is not converted while using the special tag `report` in data XMLs. So just add the field with normal XML record afterwards:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <report
            id = "report_custom_sale_order"
            name = "custom_saleorder_v2.custom_report_saleorder"
            string = "Custom Quotation / Order"
            model = "sale.order"
            report_type = "qweb-pdf"
            attachment_use = "False"
    />
    <record id="custom_module_name.report_custom_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="print_report_name"><![CDATA[((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')]]></field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

It's not converted in [Odoo 10](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/5ca0ef978f350739bf2481c04ad10215d53fb362/odoo/tools/convert.py#L288), but in [Odoo 11](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/34c52e993834948661b5436fb6a4fae1c0e44928/odoo/tools/convert.py#L284) the field was added.

Comment: Try to add your module name to the record id like `<record id="my_module.my_xml_id" ...`.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using different field for report name and object. I have updated your code as following with the proper field names.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
  <report
        id = "report_custom_sale_order"
        name = "custom_saleorder_v2.custom_report_saleorder"
        string = "Custom Quotation / Order"
        model = "sale.order"
        report_type = "qweb-pdf"
        print_report_name = "((object.name or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
        attachment_use = "False"
  />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am still getting an error. If I remove that specific line it works fine.

Comment: Please add line here in which you are getting an error.

Comment: It is the print_report_name the specific line which fails. If I remove that line it works fine.

Comment: Are you using `object.number` in _print_report_name_ attribute value? FYI, there is no field name with _number_ in sale order object. Use `object.name` instead of `object.number`.

Comment: I am using `object.name` I already realized that there is no `object.number`. It seems that the issue might be related to the `<report>` usage. I will test what CZoellner suggests,

Comment: CZoellner's answer fix this issue in Odoo 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print_report_name`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <report id = "report_custom_sale_order"
            name = "custom_saleorder_v2.custom_report_saleorder"
            string = "Custom Quotation / Order"
            model = "sale.order"
            report_type = "qweb-pdf"
            print_report_name = "((object.number or 'SaleOrder').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
            attachment_use = "False" />
</odoo>
```

Comment: I still get the same error.  If I remove that specific line it works fine.